Steam API to go through a game's community tabs?
I'm looking for the best way to get data from a game's community tab using steam's API. I'm hoping to track when a game has a new update published, popular artwork, mod updates, that type of thing. Upon looking around it seems the Steam API is quite limited when it comes to getting community information, and there are any endpoints for accessing the data of a game's community page directly.

Yeah, Valve doesn't/is slow to update existing documentation with changes, let alone make new docs. Likely have to scrape the data.
